Unable to Retrieve Sheets Subordinated to a Collection in Autodesk Construction Cloud API
I am currently working with the Autodesk Construction Cloud API to fetch sheets and version sets. However, I'm facing a challenge where I cannot retrieve sheets or version sets that have been grouped within a collection. While I can successfully fetch ungrouped sheets and version sets, those organized within a collection are absent from the response. This issue persists both for sheets and version sets.
The Get request i am using
I created a new project without Collections enabled and was able to retrieve all sheets without any issues. After activating a collection and creating one, I could still retrieve the sheets. However, as soon as I moved a sheet to a collection, it was no longer present in my API response.

thank you for reporting. I can reproduce this issue. Please bear with me checking with engineer team.

first, it is true this is a gap with current API. We apologized for this. Although the ideal solution is to expose API for Collection, it may take time until its final release, so our engineer team is planning to expose the support to get sheets of collection based on current API.  i.e. only get them as common sheets. We cannot guarantee when it would be available.  Please better check back after summer time. At that moment, we may know what is the update.  We appreciate your understanding and patience.
